# Unable to display third largest number using a while loop without array

Tags: java, while-loop

My code asks the user to enter three numbers and it supposed to display the third number you enter . I have been troubleshooting this code for at least an hour now , but no avail.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class thirdLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int largest = 0;
        int secondLargest = 0;
        int thirdLargest = 0;

        int counter = 0;
        int number;

        while (counter < 4) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            number = input.nextInt();

            if (number > largest) {
                number = largest;
                largest = secondLargest;
            } else if (number > secondLargest) {
                number = secondLargest;
                secondLargest = thirdLargest;

            } else if (number > thirdLargest) {
                thirdLargest = number;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Third largest number is " + thirdLargest);
    }
}
```

Here is the output

> Enter a number
>   99
>   Enter a number
>   88
>   Enter a number
>   77
>   Enter a number
>   66
>   Enter a number
>   55
>   Third largest number is 0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If the user enters consecutively larger numbers, `if(number>largest){` will always be true, meaning third largest will never be set.  I think you need a re-write.

Comment: Apart from the logic error(s), which you should figure out through debugging, you don't seem to understand how assignment works... half of the time. `number=largest` changes `number`, not `largest`.

Comment: largest also stays at 0, does not get past the first if statement, needs rewriting

Comment: I suggest putting `System.out.println(counter + " " + largest + " " + secondLargest + " " + thirdLargest);` before your `counter++` -- this will help you see what's going on. You could also put e.g. `System.out.println("if(A)");` inside each `if/else block`. Better still, use a debugger. It's never too early to learn.

Comment: PS hopefully this is a step towards learning that "without arrays" (or "without Lists") is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try

1) storing the user input in an ArrayList of int

2) sort the array using Collection.Sort(yourList)

3) print the first element in the list yourlist.get(0)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int number;

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number=input.nextInt();
    al.add(number);
}
Collection.Sort(al);
int largest= al.get(2) ;
int secondLargest= al.get(1);
int thirdLargest= al.get(0);
System.out.println("Third largest number is "+thirdLargest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the following code will work using your logic, without arrays. Though I haven't run it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class thirdLargest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int largest=0;
    int secondLargest=0;
    int thirdLargest=0;

    int counter=0;
    int number;

    while(counter<4){
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number=input.nextInt();
        if (number > largest){
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = number;
        }
        else if (number > secondLargest){
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = number;
        }
        else if (number > thirdLargest){
            thirdLargest = number
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Third largest number is "+thirdLargest);
}
```